# How do I delete a key/value pair from a sqlite db in an ionic 4 App

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic4

I am using the following code to get the keys from a sqlite db and display them in an ion-list.  What I am trying to accomplish is use the deleteKeyValue() method to delete the selected key {{loop[i]}} from the sqlite db.  What I am missing is how I would pass the value of {{loop[i]}} into this.storage.remove("");  Thank you you in advance into any help in this matter.

.ts

```
// Traverse key/value pairs

listKeys() {
  this.storage.keys().then((k) => {
    console.table(k)
    this.loop = k;
    console.log("key value", this.loop);
  });
}

// Delete selected key/value pair

deleteKeyValue() {
  console.log("Delete key");
  this.storage.remove('passed value from {{loop[i]}} as string');
}
```

.html

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item-divider>
        <ion-label>
          List of rows
        </ion-label>
      </ion-item-divider>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let list of loop; index as i">
      <ion-item>
          {{loop[i]}}
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item-options side="end">
        <ion-item-option (click)="deleteKeyValue()" color="danger">
            <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="trash"></ion-icon>
          </ion-item-option>
      </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
```

[image: screen capture of console.log]

Comment: Values are stored in a "key:value" format. So you need to know the key to remove a item. Remove works the same as Get, this.storage.remove("key"). Knowing the the flux of your app you should know the key names that are stored in the app.

Comment: {{loop[i]}} actually displays a list of keys.  What I am trying to do is pass the key name into (click)="deleteKeyValue()

Comment: Please post this array of keys

Comment: screen capture added

Comment: Check if this works console.log(this.storage.get("AcessToken"));

Comment: Yes it will work, I use that for page auth

Comment: Then this.storage.remove("AcessToken");  should remove the item from storage.

Comment: of course it will.  check out the deleteKeyValue() in the .ts file and you will see it written there.  I am trying to pass the value into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up with

html

```
<ion-list lines="inset">
  <ion-item-divider>
    <ion-label>
      List of Audits
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item-divider>
  <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let list of loop; index as i">
    <ion-item>
        {{loop[i]}}
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options side="end">
      <ion-item-option (click)="deleteKeyValue( loop[i] )" color="danger">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="trash"></ion-icon>
      </ion-item-option>
    </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

.ts

```
// Traverse key/value pairs
listKeys() {
  this.storage.keys().then((k) => {
    console.table(k)
    this.loop = k;
    console.log("key value", this.loop);
  });
}

// Delete selected key/value pair

deleteKeyValue(value: string) {  // infer the value as a string
    console.log("test", value);
    this.storage.remove(value).then(() => {
      this.listKeys();  // refreshes list
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  deleteKeyValue(value) {
   this.storage.remove(value);
  }

  this.deleteKeyValue(this.loop[i]);
```

Comment: Your answer did not work, but it got me thinking in the right direction.  Thanks